# Changing the default proxy port on nginx default file to a different port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have nginx installed on my local ubuntu 16.04 system. I am just starting to understand nginx before I use it on production.

I have a rails application running on `localhost:3000`

I wanted to establish a **proxy** server between the browser/client and the main application running on `localhost:3000`. By going through some answers I tried changing the default `listen 80 default_server;` to `listen 3000 default_server;`. It didn't work.

I am attaching the edited `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file I tried. Please let me know how can I establish a proxy so that it listens to `3000` port.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 3000 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question well you want nginx to listen on port 80 and pass all incoming requests to a Rails application running on port 3000. You can achieve by changing the location block to:

```
listen 80;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

It will grab all requests and pass them on to port 3000 on the host nginx runs on.

Comment: This seems to work but looks like the one serving from proxy server lacks all the assets ,images, css. What can be the issue ?

Comment: This works only for home page. When click on any other button/other request it is throwing 404 error.